# Is there a way assign only new values not the new variables in objects

Tags: javascript

I have

```
objectA = {a : 1, b:2}
```

and

```
objectB = {a:3, b:4, c:5}
```

what is the easiest possible way to get the below answer

```
objectA = {a:3, b:4}
```

I got a similar problem `objectA` has 40 properties and response `objectB` has 28+15 new properties, in which 28 properties are in `objectA`. Simply assigning the property to property is tedious way.

Comment: if objectA = {a: 1, b:2, z:7} and objectB = {a:3, b:4, c:5} should the result still be objectA = {a: 3, b:4} because you mention that objectA has 40 variables, 28 of which are duplicated in object B and you want objectB values to override, but what do you want to happen with the other 12 variables in objectA that are not in objectB?

Comment: `a`, `b` and `c` are not variables. `objectA` and `objectB` are variables. They contain values of type `Object`. `a`, `b` and `c` are properties of these objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
const objectA = {a:1, b:2};
const objectB = {a:3, b:4, c:5};
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(objectA)) {
  objectA[key] = objectB[key]
}
console.log(objectA) // {a: 3, b: 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this way?

```js
    let objectA = { a : 1, b: 2 };
    const objectB = { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 };
    objectA = { 
        ...objectA,
        ...Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(objectB).filter(
                ([key]) => Object.keys(objectA).includes(key)
            )
        )
    };
    
    console.log(objectA);
```